# Could not find cache store adapter for memory_store

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason anytime I'm running a Rails 3.0.3 application with Ruby 1.8.7. It's been running fine and I haven't set any `cache_store` settings anywhere. Now anytime I try to run `rake` tasks or `rails` command I get this:

```
$:rails console production
/home/marc_m3pt0/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/cache.rb:65:in `lookup_store': Could not find cache store adapter for memory_store (no such file to load -- active_support/cache/memory_store) (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:48
    from /home/marc_m3pt0/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    from /home/marc_m3pt0/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:22:in `with_warnings'
    from /home/marc_m3pt0/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:48
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /home/marc_m3pt0/m3pt0.com/config/environment.rb:5
    from /home/marc_m3pt0/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /home/marc_m3pt0/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /home/marc_m3pt0/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/marc_m3pt0/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/marc_m3pt0/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/marc_m3pt0/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:22
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Any ideas on what I could be missing?

Thanks so much. My clients site is down right now so any help soon would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

When I run rake tasks I get this:

```
Could not find cache store adapter for memory_store (no such file to load -- active_support/cache/memory_store)
```

Comment: Do you see anything different when you run `bundle exec rails console production`?

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error recently when a shared host moved an application to a new server. I ended up blowing away the application's bundle and reinstalling it, and it seemed to work.

I use Capistrano for deployment, so if you use something else, YMMV. If your application root is this:

```
/home/jeff/myapp/
```

with the following subdirectories:

```
/home/jeff/myapp/current
/home/jeff/myapp/releases
/home/jeff/myapp/shared
```

the gem bundle is here:

```
/home/jeff/myapp/shared/bundle
```

Then I did:

```
rm -rf /home/jeff/myapp/shared/bundle
```

then

```
cd /home/jeff/myapp
bundle install
```

Once I did this, it seemed to work for me.

Comment: I don't have any of those subdirectories. So I'm not sure what to do with this.