# Error while trying to run Rspec on a module that uses Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, redis

I have a problem running my tests with Rspec in Rails 5 for a module that uses redis. When I just run the rails server everything works fine. Whenever I run the Rspec command I get the following error:

```
/Users/reinierverbeek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/cache.rb:106:in `rescue in retrieve_store_class': Could not find cache store adapter for redis_store (cannot load such file -- active_support/cache/redis_store) (RuntimeError)
from /Users/reinierverbeek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/cache.rb:104:in `retrieve_store_class'
```

My Redis object is initialized in the initializer file as follows :

```
$redis = Redis::Namespace.new("ghanagana", :redis => Redis.new)
```

In the configuration file I have the following line:

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store, 'redis://localhost:6379/0/cache'
```

Edit: I am running the redis server on the specified port

Comment: You need to run redis server as well before starting your tests.

Answer (score 0):

you must have gem `redis-store`in your Gemfile and you need to add this

```
require 'redis-server'
```

in the environment file or some specific test file. 
Moreover, Please make sure that you have Redis server running by going to redis [url](http://localhost:6379).

You may also check this soulution if it works for you. [Could not find cache store adapter for memory_store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439198/could-not-find-cache-store-adapter-for-memory-store)

Comment: This didn't fix the issue unfortunately, error still the same